# Is there a hook attached to general settings save?

Tags: plugins, options

I want to add a field to the general settings page, but I can not save the field because I can't find a hook for the pages save.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to `register_setting()` on your setting and it will be saved automatically. See the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) for more info. Here's a complete example:

```
function spw_cb() {
    if( !($value = get_option('sprockets_per_widget')) ) {
        $value = 7;
    }

    ?>
    <input type="text" size="3" name="sprockets_per_widget" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /> Numeric only!
    <?php
}

function spw_init() {
    add_settings_field('sprockets_per_widget', 'Sprockets per Widget', 'spw_cb', 'general');
    register_setting('general', 'sprockets_per_widget', 'intval');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'spw_init');
```